# Detecting the end of an animation on a MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, maps, mkmapview

I have an MKMapView that is animated to the user's location:

```
MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.5;
mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.5; 

[mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
```

I need to find the top-left and bottom-right coordinates of the current view AFTER the animation is complete. Is there a way I can detect when the animation ends?

And actually, if it is simpler, is there a way to find the top-left and bottom-right lat/long coordinates of a MKCoordinateRegion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real sure way to tell when the map has truly finished but for what you are doing, `mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap` *may* be close enough. From there you can convert using `convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:` to get the coord of amy points on your map.